# Mocha not calling my function in my test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocha.js

I have this test:

```
it('calls addTheItem when clicked', () => {
  wrapper.find('.addBtn').simulate('click')
  expect(addTheItemStub.called).to.equal(true)
});
```

This is my code

```
<button
  className="addBtn"
  onClick={() => {this.addTheItem(inputValue); this.clearInput()}}
  >
  Add Item
</button>
```

This code works when I play around with it. just the test isn't passing.

also in my beforeEach:

```
    const addTheItemStub = sinon.spy();
    const addItemStub = sinon.spy();
    const usingEnterKeyStub = sinon.spy();
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(
        <Container
          addTheItem={addTheItemStub}
          addItem={addItemStub}
          items={itemsStub}
          usingEnterKey={usingEnterKeyStub}
        />
      )
    });
```

I'm stubbing it out. I'm expecting the stub to be called.

but it's expecting it to be not called or false. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in button's onClick handler, you are calling your methods as `this.addTheItem` and `this.clearInput`. But you are passing the stubs for these methods as props to the parent `Container` element.

The stubs won't be called unless you use the methods from props, i.e., `this.props.addTheItem` and `this.props.clearInput`.

Comment: ah yes, so my bad. these functions are not props. they are just class methods, how can I test the calling of class methods?

Comment: This is where the dependency injection principle comes into play :). You can't test whether something is called, unless it is passed from outside. Try to change the design so that you pass these methods as callbacks in `props`.

Comment: sorry what? you can never test a react component which has a method on the class?

Comment: Suppose you have a component like this: https://pastebin.com/vk98pg3g. You cannot directly test whether method1 was called or not, because you cannot stub it in your unit test. You can stub method2, because it is passed from outside to the component. You can test method1 indirectly, by asserting on any side-effect caused by it. For eg, if it appends something to a list and you have access to the list, you can check it contents and infer that method1 was called.

Comment: oh really I didn't realise that, I just thought that you test the components in that unit. are we able to speak somewhere else as i have a couple of other questions? cheers!

Comment: ok cheers. so one final question, is the inferring of a method being called good practice?